# Possible Reasons of Reconsuming Kafka Messages

Tags: go, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, sarama

Yesterday I found from log the kafka was reconsuming some messages after the Kafka group coordinator initiated a group rebalance. These messages had been consumed two days ago (confirmed from log).

There were two other rebalancing reported in the log, but they didn't reconsume messages anymore. So why the first time reblancing would cause reconsuming messages?  What were the problems?

I am using the golang kafka client. here are the code

```
config := sarama.NewConfig()
config.Version = version
config.Consumer.Offsets.Initial = sarama.OffsetOldest
```

and we are handling messges before claiming messages, so seems we are using the Send At Least Once strategy for kafka. We have three brokers in one machine, and only one consumer thread (go routine) in the other machine.

Any explanations for this phoenomenon? 
I think the messages must have been committed, coz they were consumed two days ago, or why would kafka keep offsets for more than two days without committing?

Consuming Code sample:

```
func (consumer *Consumer) ConsumeClaim(session 
sarama.ConsumerGroupSession, claim sarama.ConsumerGroupClaim) error {

for message := range claim.Messages() {
    realHanlder(message)   // consumed data here
    session.MarkMessage(message, "") // mark offset
}

return nil
}
```

Added:

1. Rebalancing happened after app restarted. There were two other restarts which didn't cuase reconnsume
2. configs of kafka

   log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
   log.retention.hours=168
   zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
   group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
   delete.topic.enable = true
   auto.create.topics.enable=false

Comment: When you are using the oldest offset you will get the messages from the oldest one that you haven't commit. Could you please share the consuming phase of your code?

Comment: What is your server retention policy? And does your group identification change in rebalance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading the source code of both golang saram client and kafka server, finally I found the reason as below

1. **Consumer group offset** retention time is **24hours**, which is a default setting by kafka, while **log** retention is **7days** explicitly set by us.
2. My server app is running in test environment where few people can visit, which means there may be few messages produced by kafka producer, and then the consumer group has few messages to consumes, thus the consumer may not commit any offset for long time.
3. When the consume offset is not updated for more than 24hours, due to the offset config, the kafka broker/coordinator will remove the consume offset from partitions. Next time the saram queries from kafka broker where the offset is, of course client gets nothing. Notice we are using **sarama.OffsetOldest** as initial value, then sarama client will consume messages from the start of messages kept by kafka broker, which results in messages reconsuming, and this is likely to happen because log retention is **7days**